# List of Reusable Components - Ideas C# and ASP.NET

Tags: components, code-reuse, rad

We are planning to build a library of ReUsable Components so that we can reuse them and improve the productivity across all projects of the company.

We have prepared a list of components, but I couldn't share the complete list here as it is not my personal but official.

Examples of few of such components in our minds are Excel Export / Import etc.

I would need your help in expanding the list of such components.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling can be an example of a  re-usable component.

Answer (score 0):

User Audit Log,
Notification Services (Email / SMS / Popup),
FileService - (like AWS S3),
IdentityProvider,
ExcelExport,
EDI Components,
Grid,
File Selection Popup Control,
Excel Import & etc.,